# Using a ContentPresenter for a custom control (Thumb)

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a custom control that allows for drag using the DragDelta of the Thumb control. I want to be able to insert a Shape, Image or TextBlock inside the custom control ContentPresenter.

**CustomControl.xaml (Thumb)**

```
<Thumb x:Class="StackOverflow.CustomControl"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Thumb.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Thumb.Template>
</Thumb>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow">
    <local:CustomControl>
        <!--Shape, Image or TextBlock-->
    </local:CustomControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: Since `Thumb` doesn't derive from `ContentControl`, I think you're going to have to give your class a `Content` dependency property of type `Object`, and give the custom control class these two attributes: `[ContentProperty("Content")][DefaultProperty("Content")]`.

Comment: ...and give the `ControlTemplate` `TargetType="local:CustomControl"`, whatever your thumb class is actually called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `Content` property is `Object`, you can put anything in there that will go in a `ContentControl`: Visual tree elements, strings, a viewmodel with an implicit `DataTemplate` (pretty farfetched in this particular case, but it's the principle of the thing) -- you name it.

MyThumb.xaml

```
<Thumb 
    x:Class="ThumbTest.MyThumb"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:thumb="clr-namespace:ThumbTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" 
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    >
    <Thumb.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="thumb:MyThumb">
            <ContentPresenter 
                />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Thumb.Template>
</Thumb>
```

VS is giving me a blue squiggle under `<Thumb...` in the XAML because the `TargetType` of the `ControlTemplate` doesn't match, but it builds and works fine. This change to the template will get rid of that:

```
<Thumb.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="thumb:MyThumb">
        <ContentControl
            Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=thumb:MyThumb}}"
            />
    </ControlTemplate>
</Thumb.Template>
```

MyThumb.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace ThumbTest
{
    [ContentProperty("Content")]
    public partial class MyThumb : Thumb
    {
        public MyThumb()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Content Property
        public Object Content
        {
            get { return (Object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(Object), typeof(MyThumb),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));
        #endregion Content Property
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Ed Plunkett

**CustomControl.xaml.cs (Thumb)**

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public partial class CustomControl : Thumb
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public FrameworkElement Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No need to make it `FrameworkElement`; `Object` works as well for visual tree elements, but also lets you do strings or viewmodels with implicit DataTemplates.